# SQL Insert when not exist where dataset is from select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, upsert

I am trying to execute following query

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2)
SELECT Column1Value, 'Temp'   -- This will return multiple values which are to be inserted.
FROM Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.Column1 = t3.Column1
    ...
    Few more joins
    ...
WHERE t2.Column3 = 0
```

As you can see in Insert query data rows are coming from another query. (And that's why I can't use `WHERE != something` here)
I am able to run this query but the problem is when few records already exists this will throw and exception. So I need to make sure this query gets executed only for those records which doesn't exists.

Can anybody help?

Thanks & regards,

Ganesh.

Comment: Primary key of MyTable? Add NOT EXISTS to the SELECT part.

Comment: Switch to a MERGE WHEN NOT MATCHED instead

Comment: @jarlh Primary key is auto generated

Comment: @dnoeth I'm not expert at SQL. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you show the constraints, PK/FKs, of the target table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2)
SELECT Column1Value, 'Temp'
FROM Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.Column1 = t3.Column1
    ...
    Few more joins
    ...
WHERE t2.Column3 = 0
AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT Column1 FROM MyTable MT WHERE MT.col1 = t2.col1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Donal, 
This works fine. 
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a condition such as:

```
where not exists (select 1
                  from mytable t
                  where t.column1 = column1value and t.column2 = 'temp'
                 )
```

This assumes that the two columns together constitute a unique or primary key.

It is also possible that your select is returning duplicate values, which is causing the problem.  So, you might also change the `select` to `select distinct`:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2)
    SELECT DISTINCT Column1Value, 'Temp'
    FROM Table2 t2
        INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.Column1 = t3.Column1
        ...
        Few more joins
        ...
    WHERE t2.Column3 = 0 AND
          NOT EXISTS (select 1
                      from mytable t
                      where t.column1 = column1value and t.column2 = 'temp'
                     );
```

Comment: I could've done that but the problem is values that I'm going to insert are coming at run time from the Select query. So I can't embed them into the query.

And we've designed our database such as there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: @GaneshS . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  This is a modification of the query in your question that should prevent duplicates from being inserted into `MyTable`.  That appears to be the question you are asking.  If you have a different question, then ask another question.